# computer freezes randomly?

Tags: windows-7, freeze

For the last weeks I've been suffering a problem with a Windows 7 laptop formatted only 2 months ago. From time to time the system complete freezes for a minute or so, and then it continues working as if nothing had happened. In the meanwhile I can't even move the mouse.

I had the impression that sometimes it happened when watching videos, but now I'm almost sure it has something to do with that. Now, if I open youtube, when I try to play a video I'll se 2 seconds or so, and the computer will freeze for a minute before resuming.

What can I do / what additional tests should I try to detect the problem?

Comment: press the CAPS Lock key when you get the freeze and look if the light o the keyboard toggles.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work until the temporal freezing is over.

Comment: ok, when the light doesn't toggle it is a hardware issue during that time. check this KB and test all steps from method 3: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504/en-us#method3

Comment: 1. Overclocking: is it possible that my BIOS doesn't have this option?
2. Check the memory: Windows Memory Check passed.
3. Power supply: no change except that I'm using an electricity adaptor as I'm using my European laptop in the USA.
4. Overheating: sometimes it happens just after turning on the computer.
5. Defaults: I don't know what this refers to...

Comment: 5. go into the BIOS and load the default settings.

Comment: I did that too. Still freezing.

Comment: also check the RAM with other tools like memtest86+. Please also run CPU-Z (http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and compare that the current memory timings match to the values in the SPD tab.

Comment: Update your drivers is usually a good thing - but not via MS Updates, from the original manufacturers website

Answer (score 1):

From time to time the service **Windows Search** carries out an indexing of your files.
Streaming media is a heavy load on the system so if indexing goes on at the same time the freeze you describe is not unusual

Open the Windows Task Manager, go to the tab **Services**, click on the **button Services** (lower right hand corner). In the new window that comes up look for Windows Search. Stop or disable the service.

Comment: After doing this the computer didn't freeze for a few days but now it's happening all the time again. Not only when I use Youtube or other video/audio.